# is the following complex function is defined at deleted neighborhood of $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

the function is:

$\dfrac{2\pi z - i}{\sinh(\frac{1}{z})}$

of course the function is not defined at $z=0$, but what happen in a deleted neighborhood of that point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not defined when $\sinh(1/z)=0$. Since $\sinh w=(e^w-e^{-w})/2$, saying $\sinh w=0$ means $e^{2w}=1$, that is, $2w=2k\pi i$ for integer $k$. So the function is not defined at
$$
z=\frac{1}{k\pi i}
$$
Hence…

Answer (score 0):

It is meromorphic with an infinite number of poles.